# rand() выдает одинаковое число

Tags: c++, случайные-числа

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "string"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;



int main()
{
    cout << "Make the number from 1 to 6" << endl;
    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));
    int number = rand() % 6+1;
    string answer;

    do {
        cout << "Is your number " << number << "?" << endl;
        cin >> answer;

        if (answer == "yes")
        {
            cout << "Your number is " << number << endl;
        }


    }
    while (answer!="yes");




return 0;
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Есть код выше. По идее, каждый цикл он должен у юзера спрашивать, правильное ли число он загадал (юзер в голове число держит). Число от 1 до 6 и оно должно каждый цикл быть разным. Когда программа отгадает, выводит инструкцию из if.
Но у меня постоянно выбивается число 6 вместо разных чисел. В каком месте я ошибся?

Comment: Ну если оно каждую итерацию цикла должно быть разным - поставьте получение случайного числа в цикл.

Comment: вот блин, и правда. Спасибо)

Comment: Советую попробовать использовать генераторы с++11 - они намного удобнее. Тут есть пример: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution , аналогично для дробных: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution

Answer (score 0):

> Число от 1 до 6 и оно должно каждый цикл быть разным.

Ну если оно каждую итерацию цикла должно быть разным - поставьте получение случайного числа в цикл.

Answer (score -2):

Привет. Попробуй перед тем, как ты будешь использовать ф-ию `rand` вызвать ф-ию `randomize` для инициализации.

```
 ...
 randomize();
 int number = rand() % 6+1;
 string answer;
 ...
```

Comment: @Олег Только один раз в программе, а то, бывает, находятся люди, которые перед каждым вызовом `rand()` догадываются это делать... И еще - вызывается это обычно как `srand(time(0))`.

Comment: Что такое `randomize()`??? В стандартной библиотеке языка С++ нет такой функции.